# binding a checkbox value with a textblock text on xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I want to bind a checkbox values `ischecked=true` or `ischecked=false` with a `textblock` text **"Activé"** or **"Désactivé"** only on Xaml and without using a code behind is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Take a look at DataTriggers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out datatriggers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

And here is an example that should work for you.

```
<CheckBox Name="MyCheckBox" Content="IsActive"/>
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Activé"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Désactivé"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```